# SQL Server table is locked

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2012

I am trying to insert a record into a table, but I cannot. The execution never ends. I can do select though.
I guess something locking my table? How can I find out what does it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to insert your record.  Then while it is waiting, go to another SSMS session and execute `sp_Who2` and show us the output.

Comment: @RBarryYoung The output is large. Should I look for a particular Status, or Command, or anything else?

Comment: See if there are any rows in the output where the `BlkBy` is not blank ('.').  If so then show us those rows and any other rows with a `SPID` value that matches the values in `BlkBy`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I found one such record in the output:
72    SUSPENDED                      RLGY\johnsmith somemachine-01 85    BA_SALES INSERT           344 18 12/03 13:32:44 .Net SqlClient Data Provider                   72    0

Comment: @DavidShochet Then what does the line for SPID 85 show?

Comment: @RBarryYoung 85    SUSPENDED                      RLGY\thisIsMyself mymachine-2  81    master INSERT           140 15 12/03 12:47:43 Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query 85    0

Comment: @DavidShochet And then what does the line for SPID 81 show? (this would be easier if you added the output to your post.  Then I could edit it down to the relevant lines).

Comment: @RBarryYoung That one has BlkBy "-". It seems like the first one was the cause, doesn't it? 
I am not sure I am allowed to display all that information...

Comment: Nope, its the other way around.  The last one (81) is the likely source.  What's the whole line like?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I lost already the result. But I hope that next time I will know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the necessary permissions for the following, you can run then in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to find out the processes that are locking tables.

```
sp_who
sp_who2
sp_lock
```

Then you can `KILL` the process in question by taking the Process ID from 1 of the above SPs.

```
-- Kill Server process ID 123
KILL 123
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but the output does not explain to me anything. How can I recognize what the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried `sp_who2` ? That should show the actual command executing. Maybe you can identify your SQL from that?

Comment: There's also this extended sp code that might help. http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/23eeb821-2a42-429d-8d94-aee96224701d

Comment: Hmmm, suddenly the record was inserted. I guess whoever was locking the table stopped doing it. Thank you all for the suggestions.
I guess now it is impossible to find out who was locking the table... unfortunately...

Comment: You can also do DBCC INPUTBUFFER(SPID) to see what they were doing.

Comment: What SPID would the OP be providing for the DBCC? Wouldn't that also be gone already? @samyi

Comment: @Shiva, Correct. If you've killed it already.. it's gone. You'll have to put in the SPID of the process that is blocking your process. So if it happens again.. run sp_who2 to see if your process is blocked... then put int he SPID of the process that is blocking it.